# Different behavior of app on Xcode 4 and Xcode 5 using iOS7

Tags: xcode4, ios7, uinavigationbar, xcode5, uitoolbar

I'm building an app on Xcode 4 as well in Xcode 5 on iPhone 5 (iOS 7) device. The app contains Navigation Bar and UIToolbar on launch of MainViewController.

Now, the question is that when app is build from Xcode 4 then NavigationBar and UIToolbar is shown in iOS 6 default (Navy Blue color) also all controls behave according to iOS 6 standard.
If it is built from Xcode 5 then all controls behave according to iOS 7 standard.

I would like to know the reason. Also, how can I make this consistent?

Comment: the iOS SDK version is different. You should note the difference among iOS SDK versions.

Answer (score 0):

Please check below link.

[iOS 7 UI Transition Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TransitionGuide/Bars.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013174-CH8-SW1)